# How to create a nested DRF serializer with a UUID PrimaryKeyRelatedField?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I've simplified/minimised the example here (removed class meta which specifies model and all fields, removed some other explicitfields) but it matches the use case and replicates the behaviour being observed.

```
class MainSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    a = ASerializer(required=False, many=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        a_data = validated_data.pop("a", None)
        main_instance = super().create(validated_data)
 
        if a_data is None:
            return main_instance
 
        for a in a_data:
            a["main_relation"] = main_instance
        a_serializer = ASerializer(data=a, many=True)
        a_saved = None
        if a_serializer.is_valid():
            a_serializer.save()
            a_saved = a_serializer.data
        else:
            a_saved = a_serializer.errors

        return {
            **self.data,
            "a": a_saved.data()
        }
```

```
class ASerializer(ModelSerializer):
     main_relation = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=ModelB.objects.all(),
                                        required=False, allow_null=True, default=None)
```

The `MainSerializer#create` ends up throwing an error in the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField#to_representation` where it says the string representation of `main_instance` has no attribute `pk`, but when running through the debugger, the instance definitely has both the `pk` and `uid` attribute, and both are the same value as expected. So what's going wrong?

Side question: if instead of returning the dictionary, and returning `main_instance` in both cases, will the viewset return the full `MainSerializer#data` representation of the instance (the nested a relationship included as per it's serializer)? And if the nested serializers have errors, will they come through in that data? Or would something like this require an extension of the drf functionality?

Comment: Can you share the whole stack trace

Comment: Will come back and do this when I am able!